# Current with 150 degree phase shift and wiggle on single phase motor

Tags: ac, mains, induction-motor, phase-shift

So while I was trying to solve another problem on a different [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/571815/triac-keeps-failing), I found that my AC(Air Conditioner) Unit compressor waveforms were a bit confusing; As you can see on the scope view below there's 150 degree phase shift between current and voltage. There is also another thing that confuses me the current was wiggling around as you can see in this [video](https://youtu.be/26FkEUt0vgU). Why is that happening ?

My question is why is this happening ? shouldn't the phase shift be at most 90 degrees ?

**Current = green x 10, voltage = yellow x 10**
[image]

**Update 1:**

I'm using a differential probe with a current shunt of 0.1 ohms and normal probe for the voltage. The ground of both probes are connected to each other at one end of the shunt. normal probe is connected to mains and other side of the differential probe to the other side (load side) of the shunt.

[image]

**Update 2:**

I measured another AC unit and it's phase shift was 180 degrees. I don't understand what causes this shift Also non of the AC units are inverter types.

Isn't 180 degree phase shift between current and voltage make the power always negative ? I'm really confused.

Comment: Can you update your question to explain how you are probing the current?  The wiggle looks to me like you might have averaging turned on. If so, try turning it off. Most likely you are probing the current backwards (like a current probe with the wire running through the wrong direction, for example).

Comment: @mkeith, I will check the averaging on the scope and update the question. I have measured current of another AC motor with the same method and it was fine. I have explained and uploaded a schematic of scope wiring.

Comment: The polarity for current should be correct using this method. I question whether it is safe or a good idea to connect probe grounds directly to AC neutral. I thought you were either using a current probe (hall effect probe) or a current transformer (CT) to safely get the current.

Comment: Or maybe, are you using special probes that have built-in isolation? I know those exist.

Comment: @mkeith, I did have a current probe but I couldn't find it so I made it work like this. Thanks for the warning though. Also had to tape the scope ground from the plug.

Comment: @Oli disconnecting scope earthing at the plug is also dangerous. Every metal part on the scope can be live with mains if the scope probe ground clips are accidentally on live instead of neutral.

Comment: "*Also had to tape the scope ground from the plug.*" Can you explain that further?

Comment: @Transistor, Justme explained it already; To prevent a short circuit if ground of probes accidentally become live.

Comment: It's not clear to me. What plug? The mains plug? (Bad idea.) You can see it. We can't.

Comment: @Transistor, Yes the receptacle of the scope, I tough it was obvious, sorry.

Comment: A 180 phase shift means that somehow, you have the current and voltage polarities opposite each other (or the scope is set up to display one of the channels inverted) or something like that. Try measuring a heater or incandescent lamp.

Comment: @mkeith, I have check it with an electric heater and there is no phase shift.

Comment: Are you certain the differential probe is connected the right way around? It's usually possible to swap the leads at the differential box as well as at the device.

Comment: Well, physically, a 180 degree phase shift means that the load is delivering power to the source. So there are two possibilities. When you measured 180 degrees, there was some kind of measurement error or the AC unit you were measuring was acting as a generator to deliver power to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

The current phase shift happens when we have a reactive load. The bigger the reactive load, the more the phase shift.

In single-phase motors, the 90-degree phase shift is between the *current* of the main winding and the *current* of the secondary winding, not the voltages.

Comment: I don't think that is correct, The phase shift of any pure inductor should be 90 degrees not more.

Comment: Also there are single-phase motors that have a single winding with a starter capacitor.

Comment: The starter capacitor is between the power line and the secondary winding. The capacitor is for creating the current phase shift between main winding and secondary winding.

Comment: It seems to me that you didn't understand my question; I know what the capacitor is for and where it is and I don't care about phase shifts between coils. In any case I don't think your answer is correct.